# In Unity, how can I read the color from _LightColor0 in a shader?

Tags: unity, shaders, cg

I have a scene with a point light and alpha textured (RGBA) triangle strips. I want to apply the point light color with a shader.

```
Shader "Custom/Test02" {
    Properties {
        _MainTex("Texture (RGBA)", 2D) = "gray" {}
    }
    SubShader {
        Tags { "Queue"="Transparent" "RenderType"="Transparent"  }

        Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha

        Pass {
            Tags { "LightMode" = "ForwardBase" }
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            uniform sampler2D   _MainTex;
            uniform float4      _LightColor0;

           struct vertexInput {
                float4 vertex   : POSITION;
                float4 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;
             };

            struct vertexOutput {
                float4 position : SV_POSITION;
                float4 color    : COLOR;
                float2 uv       : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            vertexOutput vert(vertexInput input) {
                vertexOutput result;

                result.position = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP, input.vertex);
                result.uv       = input.texcoord;
                result.color    = float4(_LightColor0.rgb, 1.0f);
                // result.color    = float4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
                return result;
            }

            float4 frag (vertexOutput input) : COLOR {
                float4 color = tex2D(_MainTex, input.uv);
                return color * input.color;
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

The color in `_LightColor0` is always black. How do I get the proper point light color? If the color is set to `float4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);` everything appears but without color from the point lights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was thinking wrong. I do not more passes to receive every light in the scene. I took a shortcut and used a surface shader in the end. I post it here for reference

```
Shader "Custom/Test01" {
    Properties {
        _MainTex ("Texture (RGBA)", 2D) = "white" {}
    }

    SubShader {
        Tags {
                "Queue" = "Transparent"
                "RenderType" = "Transparent"
        }

        Cull Back
        Offset 0, -1

        CGPROGRAM
        #pragma surface surf BlinnPhong alpha noforwardadd
        #include "UnityCG.cginc"

        struct Input {
                float4 color : COLOR;
                float2 uv_MainTex;
        };

        uniform sampler2D _MainTex;
        void surf(Input IN, inout SurfaceOutput o) {
                float4 texel = tex2D(_MainTex, IN.uv_MainTex);
                o.Albedo = texel.rgb * IN.color.rgb;
                o.Alpha = texel.a;
        }
        ENDCG
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`_LightColor0` is part of `Lighting.cginc`. It's an automatic include for surface shaders. In order to add it to your frag shader you need to put `#include "Lighting.cginc"`in your `Pass`

[From the docs:](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-BuiltinIncludes.html)

> Lighting.cginc - standard surface shader lighting models; automatically included when you’re writing surface shaders.